# Undefined method 'delegate' for capybara::dsl::module

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I have a capybara monkey patch to deal with jquery-ui, which works pretty well running on Ubuntu... although when moving to windows I get the following error (all dependency gems were installed successfully):

Undefined method 'delegate' for capybara::dsl::module

The line of code that this occurs is:

```
module Capybara::DSL
  delegate :datepick, :datetimepick, :timepick, to: :page
end
```

any ideas of what this could be? a bit lost of why this error is shown just by switching OS...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In standard ruby delegation is handled by the module `Forwardable`. You need to `require` and then `extend Forwardable` to access these methods like so:

```
require 'forwardable'
module Capybara::DSL
  extend Forwardable
  #notice syntax is accessor, *methods
  def_delegators :page, :datepick, :datetimepick, :timepick
end
```

The type of delegation you are trying to use right now is part of active support  `Module` Class. If you would like to use this syntax then do so like this:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/module'
module Capybara::DSL
  #active_support syntax allows a to: element in the hash to act as the accessor
  delegate :datepick, :datetimepick, :timepick, to: :page
end
```